# Flutter:base64 image not displayed when the image is big

Tags: flutter, image, base64, uri

I'm displaying list of images in my flutter app where I get the String (base64) from my api and I display the image using this code :

```
Image.memory(
    base64Decode(imageUrl),
    width: double.infinity,
    height: 200.h,
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
  )
```

the code is working fine with small images but when the image is big (over 5MB) it display only half of it or none  .
[image: that's where in first image nothing displayed and in the seconde only small part of the image displayed]

Comment: unable to reproduce your situation, I test some big base64 image and it display well, I suggest you check your base64 string and make sure it not broken.


action you can take:

1.  make sure your render is good by your own predefined data (some static base64 string)

2. check your api provide correct format of your data. is your base64 image can display well in other online tools?  see [link](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter)

Comment: Maybe you will need to provide a stricter width. I'd assume that `double.infinity` could mess with some image caching and rendering heuristics. From the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.memory.html): "Either the width and height arguments should be specified, or the widget should be placed in a context that sets tight layout constraints. Otherwise, the image dimensions will change as the image is loaded, which will result in ugly layout changes."